# Determine a set of generators for operation of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

$(f )\cap(g)$ where $f, g$ are relatively primes in a factorial domain.
I know that $(f)\cap(g)=(LCM(f,g))$. But I can't prove this correctly. Please help me in problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(f)\cap (g)\subseteq (LCM(f,g))$: if  h belongs to the left hand side then $fq=h=gp$ for some  $p,q$ in your factorial domain (let's call it $A$). But this means that $f\mid h$ and $g\mid h$ so that $LCM(f,g)\mid h$, by the very definition of LCM. Therefore $h\in (LCM(f,g))$.

$(LCM(f,g)\subseteq (f)\cap (g)$: put $m:=LCM(f,g)$ and take $k\in (m)$, i.e $k=ms$ for some $s\in A$. By definition of $m$, there exist $r,t\in A$ such that $m=fr$ and $m=gt$ ($f\mid m$ and $g\mid m$) and hence $g(ts)=k=f(rs)$. This means precisely that $k\in (f)\cap (g)$.

Ask for more details if needed.

Comment: Notice I didn't use the fact that $GCD(f,g)=1$ and this is right: think about the case $A=\mathbf{Z}$, e.g what $4\mathbf{Z}\cap 6\mathbf{Z}$ is.

Comment: I proved this on my paper as your rule but I wasn't sure.any way tanks a lot.